# Database design for spring-batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

We have our product with microservices architecture.

We have order management as one of the microservices. Usually we upload files for bulk processing of data and also functionality to download daily orders.

With increase in number of records for each file, we plan to use the spring-batch application. Most of the business are within the order microservices. Now if i develop new spring-batch application using the same database as order mgmt and by adding order management as dependency to spring-batch will solve the problem.

But is this the right design? How to architect this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

use SCDF - Spring Cloud Data Flow with the microservices scenario here. (this is the spring recommended replacement for traditional spring batch, and spring batch admin ui)

use Spring Framework - https://spring.io/

use MongoDB for Operational DB, split/scalable across DB's ELK Stack - for Logging Elastic Logstash(optional) and Kibana for Reporting.